# PL/SQL For & When Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my code,

```
Declare
For num IN 1..10 LOOP
Continue When Mod(num,2)!=0;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQL> @ E:\dbms\f7.sql
For num IN 1..10 LOOP
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:
begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
current cursor
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "FOR" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 3, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

Please someone give me a working code so I can execute !!!

Comment: `begin` is missing

Comment: I tried with Begin also but still the errors are getting displayed !

Can you please write the code in proper format ?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? You show some code with syntax errors, which therefore does NOT do what you need it to do. Are we some sort of supra-natural beings, do you think we can guess what you need your block to do, from an attempt that doesn't work and no other explanation? What do you think `continue` does, anyway? And what do you think `when` means, in your code? Did you mean `if`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `declare` block since you aren't declaring any variables, but you're missing the `begin` keyword:

```
BEGIN -- Here
    FOR num IN 1..10 LOOP
        Continue When Mod(num,2)!=0;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: After executing the code above now its showing me this error 

SQL> @ E:\dbms\f7.sql Continue When Mod(num,2)!=0; * ERROR at line 3: ORA-06550: line 3, column 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; –